# PHP - Multi-Dimensional In_Array Issues

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to make a script that checks the database if the users IP is in the Database and functions appropriate to what the result is.

If it is then Update the row with the following rules:

- Increment Tries Count by 1;
- If the tries count is more then 5 make IpBanned column set to yes;
- Set the last_try column date to UK/Ireland timezone's date and time;

If its not in the database then add the IP to the database and set the tries count to 1.

Once it has determined if the IP is added or not and has queried appropriately query again to get the current values for the rows, tries, ipbanned, last_try.

---

The Issue:

---

The in_array() wont work on multi-dimensional arrays so i'm not sure what to do to check which query I should do. Also not sure if this is the best way to do this either, Im making it so its a IP Ban after x failed tries type of thing, Since my code has 3 fail points you can end up at the code really does need to be placed in the code in 3 places so the shorter the better.

---

My Code:

---

$result1 Example: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [ip] => x.x.x.x [tries] => 1 [ipbanned] => [last_try] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) )`

```
//Get the users IP;
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//Set the Timezone to UK/Ireland;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Get the Date and Time;
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

//Setup the PDO connection settiongs;
$opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=unfed_auth";

//Create a new PDO and Set its Attributes;
$DBH = new PDO($dsn, 'unfed_admin', 'xxx', $opt);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

//Check if the users IP is added;
$res1 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT tries FROM tries WHERE ip = :ip");
$res1->bindParam(':ip', $userip);
$res1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$res1->execute();
$result1 = $res1->fetchAll();

echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
print_r($result1);

if(!empty($result1)) {

echo 'Not empty';

foreach ($result1 as $r1) {
$tries[] = $r1['tries'];
}

$res1 = null;

if($tries[0]>10) { $newipbanned = 'yes'; } else { $newipbanned = 'no'; }

$res2 = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE tries SET tries = :tries, ipbanned = :ipbanned, last_try = :last_try WHERE ip = :ip");
$res2->bindParam(':ip', $userip);
$res2->bindParam(':tries', ++$tries[0]);
$res2->bindParam(':ipbanned', $newipbanned);
$res2->bindParam(':last_try', $date);
$res2->execute();
$res2 = null;

} else {

echo 'Result1 is empty';

$res3 = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO tries (ip,tries,ipbanned,last_try) VALUES (:ip,'1','no',:date)");
$res3->bindParam(':ip', $userip);
$res3->bindParam(':date', $date);
$res3->execute();
$res3 = null;

}

//End PDO Connection;
$DBH = null;

//End Script;
//header("Location: http://crime.pw/login/?r=tttt");
exit();
```

Update:

Thanks for the help guys, The code above works and the Date issue is solved thank you for helping me :)
http://crime.pw/login

Comment: Please, post only the code related to your problem. Also, provide an example of `$result1`.

Comment: everything related to `SELECT * FROM tries` is a complete waste of resources, you should be `SELECT tries FROM tries WHERE ip = :ip`

Comment: In your first loop your storing the IP in the $ip array. So do an `if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip))`

Comment: @cmorrissey Wouldnt it throw an error or something if the IP isnt in the Database?

Comment: @Crime.PW no you will just get no results

Comment: Guys, Umm, Not sure how to say this but my Password might be in some posts revisions/logs. Can anyone please confirm on the line $DBH = new PDO(); Doesnt show my password starting with a !. I heard the revisions etc go public in tar files, Can someone please get a Moderator or Developer to confirm my password is no longer there?

Comment: @cmorrissey Okay, But why isn't it select * from when we need the other stuff like ipbanned and last_try?

Comment: @Crime.PW you can still use `*` if you want but you need the `WHERE` clause or you are selecting every entry in that table

Comment: You're supposed to use mysql to search data, not retrieve all the table in memory to find what you need with php.

Comment: Ok, I kept it set to find just tries. But I also need to find the IP's can you do something like SELECT ip,tries FROM?

Comment: I edited the foreach bit to check if !empty() and if result isnt empty then it would continue to the foreach, I have data in the database so $result1 isnt empty but apparently my output is the Empty Echo tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your issue right - you should consider using [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) instead of in_array(). It works for the associative arrays;

So this part, for example:

```
foreach($result1 as $value)
{
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $value))
{
echo "Got Irix";
}
}
```

Would turn into this

```
foreach($result1 as $row){
    if(array_search($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $row)){
        echo "Got Irix";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well from my post edit this answer really isnt related anymore, Still having some issues doe maybe you can still help?

Comment: What is the MYSQL field type you are using for date? If it's datetetime - you need to use mysql format when doing date() thing. Like this $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

Comment: Ahh yes, I had an extra a at the end (Am/Pm) Thanks